# Math => PHP to Perl

Tags: php, perl, math

I'm a PHP dev and I was wondering if someone could help me converting this code into a Perl script.

I wrote this PHP code today:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i > $i++; $i++) {
    $cut = strlen($i)/2;

    $a = substr($i,0,$cut);
    $b = strrev($a);

    $som = $a + $b;

    if((strrev($a) == $b) && (strrev($som) == $som) && ($a > 10000)) {
        echo $a . " + " . $b . " = " . $som . "\n";
    }       
}
?>
```

What it does:

If you keep this formula in mind: $a + $b = $c it basically

- Cuts $i in half, reverses the 2st part and stores into $b, and stores the first part unreversed into $a.
- Adds $a and $b into $c, and checks if $c equals $c in reverse.
- Outputs the 'palindromes' , looking like this:

  **1248 + 8421 = 9669**

I'd be very helpful if anyone could help me out :-)

Thanks in avance.

Comment: `$i > $i++`? Never expected to see that as a conditional...

Comment: Yeah .. weird way to make an infinite loop. I should fix that. Probably solves the duplicate issue.

Comment: We expect you to at least have a stab at converting your code and provide an example of how far you got. It's unfair on the community to expect it to do the complete conversion for your. Thanks.

Comment: You have incorrect algorithm. See correct solution here: http://pastie.org/2520474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Zaids advise and little thinking, some small changes:

```
use strict;

for(my $i = 1;$i > 0;$i++)
{
    my $input = $i;
    my $firstHalf = substr($input,0,length($i)/2,'');
    my $sum = $firstHalf + $input;
    if(($firstHalf == reverse($input)) && (reverse($sum) == $sum) && ($firstHalf > 1000)) {
    print $firstHalf . " + " . $input . " = " . $sum . "\n";
    }
}
```

When using `use warnings` I get a warning for the addition, have to look at this.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `length` to get the length of the input
- `substr` to cut the input
- `reverse` to check if it's a palindrome
- Define the functionality in a subroutine
- Avoid use of `$a` and `$b` as variable names
- It's a good idea to ensure that the input is numeric
- `use strict; use warnings;` when coding

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

sub is_modified_palindrome {

    my $input = shift;

    # Test input numericness
    warn("Input '$input' non-numeric"), return unless looks_like_number $input;

    my $cutIndex  = length($input)/2;                  # Don't worry about int-ing it
    my $firstHalf = substr $input, 0, $cutIndex, '';   # $input contains second half

    my $result    = $firstHalf + $input;

    return $result = reverse $result;                  # Returns true or false
}
```